# Языки программирования для приложения Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Обычно студия использует язык Java. Можно ли программировать на Android с помощью других языков? Например, языка С

Comment: Можно на Делфи, если любите диковинки ;-) (начиная с версии XE5 емнип)

Comment: Поищите игровые движки с поддержкой Android.

Comment: Для работы с С/С++ есть Android NDK и поддержка на уровне IDE Android Studio, включая редактор нативного кода CLion от JetBrains, встроенный прямо в студию, но 100℅ нативный код нельзя получить, так как сам фреймворк Android написан на Java.

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете использовать C/C++ в последних версиях Android Studio, но в основном только для оптимизации больших вычислений и каких-нибудь низкоуровневых взаимодействий с системой. Нативный UI и вообще большая часть всего написано на Java и соответственно взаимодействовать с этим можно только через языки копилирующиеся в JVM код. Кроме непосредственно Java наиболее популярны Kotlin, Groovy и Scala. Для всех трех есть плагины для Android Studio добавляющие их поддержку.

Если для вас не принципиально использовать Android Studio, то мне известно ещё 3 IDE для для более мение нативной разработки под андройд:

- Qt Creator (C++) - использует свою библиотеку визуальных компонент, так что приложения могут выглядеть не совсем "нативно".
- Embarcadero RAD Studio (Delphi) - для любителей языка дельфи, по возможностям вроде аналогичен Qt Creator, тоже использует свою библиотек компонентов.
- Microsoft Visual Studio + Xamarin Platform (C#) - в отличии от двух предыдущих IDE тут нет своей библиотеки компонентов, здесь используются так называемые биндинги к нативным Java классам так что по сути тут вам доступно почти всё что доступно из явы. Есть правда и несколько ложек дёгтя: C# компилируется в IL байт код который исполняется в виртуальной машине mono (коссплатформенная реализация .NET), в результате имеем в одном приложении две параллельно работающие виртуальные машины, при этом объекты из JVM с которыми мы работаем из C# кода оборачиваются в прокси объекты в mono, в результате чего появляется не мало не очевидных подводных камней. Хотя в целом технология вполне работоспособная и пригодная.

Answer (score 2):

[Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) - The Native Development Kit for Android позволяет писать на C/C++